# Generation of Reports In Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I have two custom records.I want to generate the reports by using those two custom records (sold information record ),In that sold information records some child records are there ,show the reports of that custom(sold information record) ..

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated ??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot build reports on custom records in Netsuite. Try to build saved search on child custom record and call the parent record fields using Netsuite standard saved searches

Regards,

Koushik T